# How to design select box using css

Tags: css

Hi everyone can anyone help me how to make my selectbox just like in the picture using css.

im new in web developing can anyone help me how to make this kind of design?

htm code:

```
<select class="black" >
<option>Here is the first option</opstion>
<option>red</opstion>
<option>white</opstion>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: Your HTML has typos: `</opstion>` should be `</option>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.black {
    background: #444444;
    border: 1px solid #26487f;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    outline: 1px solid #a5c7fe;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/sRKrK/1).

You also need to fix the mistakes in your HTML: `</opstion>` should be `</option>`.